# Are the Rebbe’s dollars muktzeh?

Tags: halacha, muktzeh

It can be considered muktzeh machmas gufo because it is money. It may be chisron kis because it’s precious. But your photo album isn’t muktzeh?

Comment: What purpose does it have on Shabbat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some relevant responsa. I included cases that don't explicitly refer to a dollar from R. Schneerson, as there is no conceptual difference as relates to this issue whether the currency is a coin or bill and whether it was received from him or some other Rebbe to the same effect.

R. Moshe Sternbuch wrote ([שו"ת תשובות והנהגות ח"א סימן רלו](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20025&st=&pgnum=169)):

> שאלה: קיבל מאדמו"ר מטבע לקמיע ורוצה לצאת בו בשבת… ולאיסור מוקצה אין
> לחוש כלל וכמבואר במ"ב סימן ש"ג ס"ק ע"ד שאם ייחדה לעולם לא להשתמש בו
> כמטבע בטלה מינה שם מטבע ואין בה אסור מוקצה, וכאן כשקיבל מהאדמו"ר מטבע
> לקמיע ביטלו לשימוש כמטבע ולכן אין לחוש כלל לאסור מוקצה… ראוי להשפיע
> עליו לסמוך בשבת שזכות השבת יועיל במקום הקמיע…

In the case of a coin received from an Admor as an amulet, there is no concern of muqsa, for if one permanently designates it for non-economic use its designation as a "coin" is nullified... it is however fitting to influence such a person to rely on the merit of Shabboth itself as a source of protection rather than an amulet.

R. Shelomo Aviner wrote (פסקי שלמה, כרך ד, עמ' צ):

> האם דולר של הרבי מלובביץ הוא מוקצה בשבת? לא כי אין האדם משתמש בו ככסף
> אלא כסגולה

In the case of a dollar received from the Rebbe of Lubavitch, it is not considered to be muqsa because it is treated as a segulah.

R. Yishaq Zilberstein (עלינו לשבח, חלק ג' ,תשובה י"ט)

> קבלתי מטבע כסף מאדמו"ר מפורסם בתור קמיע והכנסתיו לתוך נרתיק מיוחד ואני
> לובשו תמיד.  מטבע שיחדוה לעולם לקמיע והפסיקו מלהשתמש בה בתור מעות קיבלה
> שם של כלי ושוב אין בה איסור מוקצה

A coin that was permanently designated as an amulet and is no longer used as money is designated as a qeli (vessel) and is not prohibited as muqsa

R. Aharon Lieberman wrote (משנת אהרן: מוקצה, פרק יא,דף קיט):

> קיבל מטבע מאדמו"ר לקמיע מותר לטלטלו לצורך שמירה ומי שאינו בטוח בעצמו
> שאכן לא ישתמש בו לסחורה ראוי שיעשה נקב במטבע או יסגרנו באופן שלא ישתמש
> בו לסחורה

A coin received as an amulet from an Admor is permitted to be used on Shabboth, and if one is unsure of themselves that they won't use it for a commercial purpose on Shabboth, they should drill a hole in it or seal it up so that it cant be used for commerce.

Comment: Great find! Especially the one from Rav Aviner. I think it also explains what Rav Shternbuch is saying.

Comment: so from these sources you are saying the dollar is either a קמיע or it's a סגולה according to one of them but what makes it into either of these things exactly? If someone took one of these dollars to a store and spent it the person at the cashier would not be able to tell the difference between this dollar and another one. Where exactly is the difference found?

Comment: @Dude the difference is in the use (the relationship of the user to the object). If I take a hammer in hand to drive in nails, the hammer is muqsah. If I take it in hand to crack open nuts, it is permitted move it.

Comment: @Dude to add to my earlier comment, your question is more apt when applied to the question of whether such currency may be worn between domains on Shabboth. Presumably such an object would first need to be vetted as a קמיע מומחה.